# Where can I find the ubuntu build that works on the x1 carbon gen6

Tags: hardware-certification

according to https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201712-26045/ there is an ubuntu 16 that is certified to work with the lenovo x1 carbon gen6. Can I get it? If so where? If not, why not?

Thanks